# How to crawl a specific value out of a HTML page with python HTMLParser

Tags: python, html

Let's imagine I want to crawl a specific value out of a HTML page, but I have no clear identifier (name="abc") for that value. I have to find the value (in this case "dfgd454" through the HTML hierarchy:

```
<html><body><div id="pagecontent"><div id="container"><div id="content"><div id="tab-description"><div id="attributes">
<div class="attr">
    <span class="name">Ugug</span>
    <span class="value">dfgd454</span>
</div>
```

How can I extract that value with Python HTMLparser?

It has to be something in the way of:

```
def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'div':
            attrD = dict(attrs)
            if attrD['class'] == 'attr':
```

But I know that code is not sufficient...

Thankfull for any help because I googled a lot until now and did not find a proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use BeautifulSoup parser.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = '''<html><body><div id="pagecontent"><div id="container"><div id="content"><div id="tab-description"><div id="attributes">
<div class="attr">
    <span class="name">Ugug</span>
    <span class="value">dfgd454</span>
</div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
print soup.select('div > span.value')[0].text
```

This would select all the immediate child span tags of `div` tag which has the  class attribute value as `value`.

**Output:**

```
dfgd454
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that! But first I have to import BeautifulSoup corretly it doesn't work right now

Comment: did you install BeautifulSoup?

Comment: I tried to but pip doesnt work right now. but thats another issue i have to solve first ;)

Comment: Hi so now I got the libary running and got the following error with your code:

print soup.select('div > span.value')[0].text
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: seems like you're running python 3. If yes then try `print(soup.select('div > span.value')[0].text)`

Comment: how is the speed of htmlparser compared to beautifulsoup?